# Passing json body with Postman in mapper with REST POST - Snaplogic

Tags: json, postman, mapper, snaplogic

How do you access the data sent from **REST POST** with **Postman** if you have an open mapper in **Snaplogic**?

For example, I have inserted some **JSON** code with key and values like this:

[image: What I`m sending]

And I want to work with it and transform it in a **Mapper** snap but I can't access it. Normal expressions using "$" didn't work for me.

Comment: What you want to do you want to do something bwith response or request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using a triggered task.

At the beginning of your pipeline, use a `JSON Parser` and you'll be able to capture the whole JSON that you are passing in the body of your API call.